# How I could convert string to variable in groovy for use as groovy swingbuilder variable?

Tags: swing, variables, groovy

I need to use a groovy swingbuildervariable like this

**date.text** this variable obtain the text from box in swing

but  I need invoke this variable from string "date;name"

for example **"date;name".split(";")[0]**

and use this for obtain text  but this is string not variable I need convert to variable Please help me

this is my code

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder 
import groovy.beans.Bindable 
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
import java.awt.*
    def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
    swingBuilder.edt {  
        frame(title: 'Address', size: [350, 230],
                show: true, locationRelativeTo: null,
                defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
            borderLayout(vgap: 5)

            panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER,
                    border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Enter your address:')])) {
                tableLayout {
    tr{

      td {       textField  id:"date",text="01-01-18", columns: 10     } 
    }
    }

     }

       } 
    }
```

Please help me

UpDate

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder 
import groovy.beans.Bindable 
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
import java.awt.*



    def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
    swingBuilder.edt {  
        frame(title: 'Address', size: [350, 230],
                show: true, locationRelativeTo: null,
                defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
            borderLayout(vgap: 5)

            panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER,
                    border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Enter your address:')])) {
                tableLayout {
    tr{

      td {       textField  id:"date",text="01-01-18", columns: 10     } 
    }
    }

     }

   panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
            button text: 'Save', actionPerformed: {
zg="date.text"
println Eval.me(zg)
            }
        }



       } 
    }
```

I use this code and not works

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Maybe showing what you tried, what you expected, and how it failed?

Comment: HI recently I try with this code for example and works ; but exist another way I dont know If is secure use eval (var="4";
zg="$var";
println Eval.me(zg))

Comment: I need use a string for print A lot of data from fields

Comment: convert string to variable and use the variable for get text date.text

Comment: a date form a field of inputbox

Comment: the print name.text

Comment: Hi  I public a new code but not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the delegate in

replace:

```
println Eval.me(zg)
```

with

```
println Eval.x(delegate, "x.$zg")
```

But I'm not sure why you'd want to do this